# Select image child element in PHP array, get source and add the source in a link

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to get an image child element source and append it in a child anchor.

Here is what I have been trying:

```
<?php 
$sql="SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY id desc";
$query=mysqli_query($sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

$id=$row['id'];
$img= $row['img'];


echo "<div class='post' id='$id'>

     <img src='$img' />
     <p><a class='download'>Download</a></p>  
     </div>";
  ?>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
var post= $(".post");
var id= $(this).attr("id");
var img= id.siblings("img");
var imgsrc= img.attr("src");
$(".download").attr("href", imgsrc);
});
```

I tried to alert the var ID; it works, but I don't know what I did wrong. I can't get the image source.

Comment: You have a number of syntax errors with missing quotes. Please check your source and post corrected versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying to follow what you're doing.  I assume from your php that you're outputting multiple elements on your page.  Assuming that your generated markup looks something like this:

```
<div class="post" id="1">
    <img src="imgs/image1.jpg" />
    <p><a class="download">Download</a></p>  
</div>
<div class="post" id="2">
    <img src="imgs/image2.jpg" />
    <p><a class="download">Download</a></p>  
</div>
<div class="post" id="3">
    <img src="imgs/image3.jpg" />
    <p><a class="download">Download</a></p>  
</div>
```

If you want to iterate over all of the .post divs and add the href to the anchor tag after the page is generated, you need to do something like this to inject the href into **each** post:

```
(function($){
    $('.post').each(function(){
        var imgsrc= $(this).find('img').prop('src');
        $('.download').prop('href', imgsrc);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Having said that, I have no idea why you wouldn't just output that directly from php in your while clause:

```
<?php 
$sql="SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY id desc";
$query=mysqli_query($sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $id=$row['id'];
    $img= $row['img'];
    echo '<div class="post" id="$id">
         <img src="$img" />
         <p><a class="download" href="$img">Download</a></p>  
         </div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works!. I could echo it in my php. I am just trying to think the other way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = $(this).attr("id");
var img = id.sibling("img");
```

You cannot get the sibling of an ID attribute.

```
var img = $(this).siblings('img');
```

I don't think **.sibling()** is even a jQuery method. Use **[.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)**.

Comment: I just tried the code. I got the alert with no image source